# Update of Referenced Cells When a Workbook is Replaced

Tags: microsoft-excel

To preface, I am running simulations that have multiple states. Each state's results is 'manually' exported into its own workbook. By manually I mean I use an "export to..." function in the sim software. The data from all of the state workbooks is compared in a separate excel file I have made that references each state workbook. The simulation software does not do an internal comparison so I have to go through this process every time I change anything in my model.

When I update my simulation and rerun all of the states I export the new results to, for example, State1-1.exe, delete the old state file (State1.exe) then rename the new state file to State1.exe. This is all done in the same folder so the reference path does not change. The comparison workbook's cells do not update until the new State1.exe is opened.

I have also tried to replace the file directly and the comparison file does not update until the replacement state file is opened.

Is there any way or maybe a different method to go about this data comparison to have the comparison file update as soon as the new state workbook is renamed to the old workbook?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did the Workbook generate automatically? Did you save the new Workbook at the same folder? Did you try to replace the old one directly?

Comment: how are you pulling in the data? formulas, VBA, powerQuery? With powerQuery you should be able to change the refresh behavior, VBA you can obviously program a refresh/open state1.